# Two-way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

i am a true R-dummy, however, i need to write a report for my internship.
I have the following data: 5 subjects have performed 6 tests. I have observational data (ethogram, its about parrots) for 2 to 4 days (time) for each test.
I am trying to figure out how to find out if there is a difference in certain behaviours between tests, but i also have to take into account the time. One of the things i am interested in, is time spent on enrichments.
This is what my data looks like that im using for enrichments:

```
> tail(Enrichments)
subject  test  time  enrichmentduration
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>              <dbl>
1 woody   ab    t3                2.79
2 woody   ab    t4                4.19
3 woody   b     t1                113.  
4 woody   b     t2                161.  
5 woody   b     t3                54.3 
6 woody   b     t4                91.4
```

I tried the following ANOVA:

```
> results3 = aov(Enrichments$enrichmentduration ~ Enrichments$test*Enrichments$time + Error(Enrichments$subject/(Enrichments$test*Enrichments$time)))
> summary(results3)
#####The summary included this, the only one with something significant#####
Error: Enrichments$subject:Enrichments$test
                                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Enrichments$test                   2 147368   73684
Enrichments$time                   1   8992    8992
Enrichments$test:Enrichments$time  1   1145    1145
Residuals                          4  10475    2619
                                  F value Pr(>F)   
Enrichments$test                   28.137 0.0044 **
Enrichments$time                    3.434 0.1375   
Enrichments$test:Enrichments$time   0.437 0.5447   
Residuals
```

Can anyone tell me if i am doing it correctly like this? And i am not sure what this significant result means, is there a significant difference between test & subject?
I have tried followup mean comparisons from some youtube-video, but i dont understand the output (an example here):

```
> krusk.test1 = with(Enrichments, kruskal(y=enrichmentduration, trt = test, alpha = 0.05, p.adj="bonferroni", group=TRUE))
> krusk.test1

$statistics
     Chisq Df      p.chisq
  29.51939  2 3.889957e-07

$parameters
            test  p.ajusted name.t ntr alpha
  Kruskal-Wallis bonferroni   test   3  0.05

$means
   enrichmentduration     rank       std  r      Min
a            4.578788  9.25000  7.575656 10  0.00000
ab          17.940439 14.82143 15.689511 14  0.00000
b          140.477553 32.50000 53.042860 16 54.31324
         Max         Q25        Q50        Q75
a   24.31824   0.1035066   1.704051   5.293144
ab  42.17142   3.1431905  20.035825  32.000018
b  228.18940 106.3268668 130.229247 179.491016

$comparison
NULL

$groups
   enrichmentduration groups
b            32.50000      a
ab           14.82143      b
a             9.25000      b

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"
```

If anyone has ~any~ suggestions on what i can do to analyse this, i will be forever grateful. Or if anyone has time to explain it to me, you'd be my savior. I dont really know how to analyse the data i have to be honest.